# Feross's simple-peer what is the code example?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to follow this page https://github.com/feross/simple-peer

1) Install npm simple-peer (check)

2) create an html page: bundle.js is missing?

3) the next code window doesn't indicate what it is at all.
Is it the JS for the html file, or the code in node. no idea.. as browserify (if I understand correctly) allows you to use require() in the browser...

Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The document given is a little incomplete and assumes you have knowledge of module bundling, which many people dont. Anyways, to get this working, you would have to use a module bundler (like browserify or webpack).

To get started, consider bootstrapping your app using this [yeoman generator](https://github.com/sohamkamani/generator-webpack-quick-test).

1. After bootstrapping your app, add the script given in the above documentation in the source file (in `src/index.js`), after installing dependancies with `npm install`
2. Run `npm start`
3. Open `localhost:8080` and you should see the result you want.

`bundle.js` which is mentioned the the above module is the resultant javascript file after all node modules have been bundled into one browser compatible file.